# After changing permalink, the Custom Post Type doesn’t work.

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question about changing the permalink of the wordpress installation. When I change the permalink to ‚post name’ my custom post type doesn’t work. The gallery page and the single page isn’t working. I have set `flush_rewrite_rules();` in my CTP function, but this doesn’t work for me.

How can it be fixed?

```
<?php

/* CTP - Portfolio template */
if (function_exists('register_post_type')) {

    // Set up an action and create the function
    add_action('init', 'gallery_manager_register');
    function gallery_manager_register() {

        // Setting up the labels
        $labels = array(
            'name' => __('Galerij'),
            'singular_name' => __('Galerij'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'slide'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New galerij'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit galerij'),
            'new_item' => __('New galerij'),
            'view_item' => __('View galerij'),
            'search_items' => __('Search galerij'),
            'not_found' =>  __('No galerij found'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galerij found in Trash'), 
        );

        // Arguments to create post type
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'galerij', 'with_front' => false),
        );

        // Register type and custom taxonomy for type
        // Fire this during init
        register_post_type('galerij', $args);
        flush_rewrite_rules();

    }


}

?>
```

Comment: which error are you getting?

Comment: @TomásCot When I change the permalink to post name, the gallery template doesn’t work. It will fall back on the index.php. When I create a new page called ‚test’ and set the template to gallery, it works, but when I has a name of ‚galerij’ it fails...